# Как симулировать нажатие на back, android

Tags: android, functional-buttons

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ программно вызвать те же действия, что и при нажатии на back? Мне нужно не отлавливать эти нажатия в onBackPressed, не отлавливать keykode и не вызывать fm.popBackStack(), а именно имитировать полноценное нажатие на кнопку back.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20adb%20send%20back%20key%20event&es_th=1

Comment: Ссылка не помогла, но направвление мне задали верно, по ключевому слову EVENT  я не догадался искать, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поробуйте вот это использовать

```
   Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
   inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

Answer (score -3):

Если вам нужно программно вызвать нажатие кнопки назад, чтобы закрыть Activity или Fragment, то можете просто вызвать метод this.finish(); Т.к. нажатие кнопки "назад" вызовет метод onBackPress(), а тот в свою очередь выполнит по стеку назад, что в свою очередь при активной активности вызовет метод finish()

Answer (score -4):

На `Activity` попробуйте:

```
this.onBackPressed();
```

На `Fragment`:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Comment: хотел запретить закрытие приложения по кнопке назад. помог! )